# How to monitor several web projects on one server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have up to five web projects on one server. They are not that popular so they can sit together. Also, I have configured nginx to run all of them.

My question is how to monitor all of them so that I could see that for some reasons one of the projects started to be an overkill for my small server and I should move it out somewhere else or I could receive an email that one of the projects is "very popular".

Is there any free packages for ubuntu to achieve that? Or some kind of third party services.

Sorry for the question without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Newrelic free plan to monitor several apps on one server.
To separate sites (applications) for monitoring you can use *newrelic.appname* setting.

I set it in the nginx config as usual:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE 'newrelic.appname=Wordpress \n upload_max_filesize=10M \n post_max_size=10M';
```

You can find configuration settings explained for PHP agent [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-configuration).

With apps and [Server monitoring](http://newrelic.com/server-monitoring) you'll get situation under control :)

I'm planning to try [Zabbix 3](http://www.zabbix.com/) which I prefer over Newrelic, but can't say yet how it handles such case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) - powerfull open source solution for any kind of goals

3.0 - the latest version and released a few weeks ago